# How to find the sessions time from a stream of user login events in python?

Tags: python, stream

Given User Login Events continuously appearing in a stream processing system similar to this, where each line is 1 event (you can assume the pipeline is external to this program, this is a line-by-line function call):

1532926994 User01 LogOutSuccessful

1532926981 User02 LogInSuccessful

1532926982 User04 LogInFailed

1532926992 User01 LogInSuccessful

1532926986 User02 LogOutSuccessful

1532927003 User03 LogOutSuccessful

Implement a module with standard libraries (e.g. no Spark) that continuously processes these events and outputs user session durations as soon as a successful logout occurs in a structured format similar to:

{ "username": "User02”, "session_duration": 5 }

{ "username": "User05”, "session_duration": 10 }

I was asked this question in an interview and I could parse and extract the data but I was not able to store the user events and use it to compute the session time. Any guidance would be appreciated.

We have to write a python function which takes one line at a time and takes some action when we receive LogInSuccessful or LogOutSuccessful. I think we can ignore LogInFailed for the moment.

```
def get_user_session_time(stream_text):

    user_info = stream_text.split()

    if user_info[2] == 'LogInSuccessful':
       #store the data somewhere
    elif user_info[2] == 'LogOutSuccessful':
       #get the data stored in the above step 
       #compute the session time
       #print the key value pair { "username": "User02”, 
       #"session_duration": 5 }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Code without using any python library

---

```
dict={}
def event(input):
    (cur_time,user,status) = input.split()
    if status=="LogOutSuccessful" and user in dict.keys():
            for logintime,login_status in dict[user].items():
                pass
                
            logout_time =int(cur_time)-int(logintime)
            print("{username: '" + user + "' , session duration: " + str(logout_time)+"}")
            del dict[user]
    else: 
        dict[user]={cur_time:status}
  
   
event('1532926981 User01 LogInSuccessful')    
event('1532926981 User02 LogInSuccessful')
event('1532926994 User01 LogOutSuccessful')
event('1532926982 User04 LogInFailed')
event('1532927003 User02 LogOutSuccessful')
```

O/P {username: 'User01' , session duration: 13}
{username: 'User02' , session duration: 22}